# "The Tangle" white paper: How the probability of double-spending event end with this approximation (t_0 μ)/w_1?

Tags: tangle, double-spending, white-paper

If the attacker managed to obtain a nonce that gives the double‐ spending transaction a weight of at least 3<sup>n<sub>0</sub></sup> during the time interval of length t<sub>0</sub>, then the attack succeeds. The probability of this event is

[image: formula from the whitepaper]

My question: How does the above probability expression end with only this term (t<sub>0</sub>μ)/w<sub>1</sub> without the exponential term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Taylor series of the exp function to the 1st order:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Exponential_function

exp(-x) = 1 + (-x)^1/1! + (-x)^2/2! + ....

Since white paper assumes x to be small, you forget about higher order terms and only take 1st order. What remains is an approximation for exp(-x), since x^2 is really tiny, once x is already small: (so is x^3 and so on)

Resulting in:

exp(-x) = 1 - x which is same as 1 - exp(-x) = x

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is correct. Yes, the Maclaurin series ((-x)^2)/2! will be even tinier. To verify 1 - exp(-x) = x, I tried with actual number and confirmed it is true when x is small and false when x is big.